# Double a value in a column on every row

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I need to double the price of all items in a table of a database in access. Here is what the table structure looks like:

sandwich $5.12

apple    $1.25

I need it to become:

sandwich $10.24

apple    $2.50

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: As usual: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The table structure looks nothing like that :) I think you mean "here is some sample data". The structure would look like: (food_description varchar, price money)

Answer (score 3):

Use an UPDATE statement to set the price = 2 * price.

Comment: @Will I would suggesting trying it out on your own first.  If I give you a fish you won't learn how to catch any on your own.

Comment: Google TSQL UPDATE and you'll find the MSDN article. If you can't read the initial blob at the top, then scroll down to the examples. That should give you a start.

Comment: What does T-SQL have to do with it? The database here is clearly indicated as Jet/ACE/Access, not SQL Server (though for something this trivial it will likely be identical SQL).

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2010, create and save a query by navigating to **Create** > **Query Design** > **[Table Name]** > **Add** > **Close**. Right-click on the query heading and select **SQL View** to use these solutions.

To use jzd's method, you can use an update query to change the values in your table.

```
UPDATE Rates SET Rates.Price = Rates.Price*2;
```

If you want to retain the original price in the table however, a select query might be a better option.

```
SELECT Rates.Item, Price*2 AS Doubled
FROM Rates;
```

In both of these solutions, replace "**Rates**" with your **[Table Name]**. "**Item**" is the product name field, "**Price**" is the product cost field, and "**Doubled**" is an example of how to attribute a new name to a calculated field. You can always switch back to the **Design View** to see how these selectors are used to easily build SQL queries.